# How do I force the CPU to perform in order execution of a program without any loops or branches?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, cpu, cpu-architecture

Is it possible? For a small code without any branches/loops.
Are there any `gcc` flags or intrinsic instructions like SSE's for `x86` and other processor families? I am just curious since all the processors available these days follow out of order execution model.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just run your code on in-order CPU, like older Intel Atom (45nm or older) or Cortex-A5 or A8 for ARM world ([ref](http://pc.watch.impress.co.jp/video/pcw/docs/423/409/p1.pdf). It is not possible to turn on or off instruction reordering in the typical out-of-order CPU. Or you can inject something serializing (like cpuid) between every your instruction to simulate in-order execution.

Comment: @osgx..Can you put this as an answer....

Comment: noleptr, what is your task? Why do you want to in-order execution? cpuid will slow down everything and also will overwrite half of x86 registers.

Comment: @osgx....This was just out of curiosity....also to be frank...I would say some unconventional interview question....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most modern out-of-order CPUs are inherently out-of-order, without switching possible between in-order and out-of-order modes.

You can try to find some in-order CPU, and there are some:

- x86: Intel Atom (only 45 nm and older versions; they have two parallel pipelines but executes all instructions in order)
- arm: Cortex-A8, and many older cores;

While it is not possible to directly turn off instruction reordering in the typical out-of-order CPU, you can inject something *serializing* (like `cpuid` in x86 world) between every your instruction to simulate in-order execution.

There is a part of Intel manuals ([vol 3a](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html)) about serializing instructions (copied from http://objectmix.com/asm-x86-asm-370/69413-serializing-instructions.html):

> Volume 3A: System Programming Guide states
>
> 7.4 SERIALIZING INSTRUCTIONS
>
> The Intel 64 and IA-32 architectures define several serializing 
>   instructions. These instructions force the processor to complete all 
>   modifications to flags, registers, and memory by previous instructions
>   and to drain all buffered writes to memory before the next instruction
>   is fetched and executed. For example, when a MOV to control register 
>   instruction is used to load a new value into control register CR0 to 
>   enable protected mode, the processor must perform a serializing 
>   operation before it enters protected mode. This serializing operation 
>   insures that all operations that were started while the processor was
>   in  real-address mode are completed before the switch to protected
>   mode is made.
>
> The concept of serializing instructions was introduced into the IA-32
>   architecture with the Pentium processor to support parallel
>   instruction  execution. Serializing instructions have no meaning for
>   the Intel486 and  earlier processors that do not implement parallel
>   instruction execution.
>
> It is important to note that executing of serializing instructions on
>   P6  and more recent processor families constrain speculative execution
>   because the results of speculatively executed instructions are 
>   discarded. The following instructions are serializing instructions:
>
> o Privileged serializing instructions - MOV (to control register,
>   with  the exception of MOV CR8), MOV (to debug register), WRMSR, INVD,
>   INVLPG,  WBINVD, LGDT, LLDT, LIDT, and LTR.
>
> o Non-privileged serializing instructions - CPUID, IRET, and RSM.
>
> When the processor serializes instruction execution, it ensures that
>   all  pending memory transactions are completed (including writes
>   stored in  its store buffer) before it executes the next instruction.
>   Nothing can  pass a serializing instruction and a serializing
>   instruction cannot pass  any other instruction (read, write,
>   instruction fetch, or I/O). For  example, CPUID can be executed at any
>   privilege level to serialize  instruction execution with no effect on
>   program flow, except that the  EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers are
>   modified.

Comment: You are mixing two things. In-order execution is not necessarily related to ordering of memory accesses. An in-order processor may use a write-combining buffer, resulting in an "effective" order, where some store operations never occur. Also, the existence of a store buffer means that accesses to uncached regions are not ordered relative to cached accesses --they are only partially ordered.

The question is about in-order execution.

Comment: Probably, the question does not ask what "it wants to know," which is easy to happen in this area of ordering....

Comment: kavadis, is my answer about memory ordering?

Comment: Is in-order execution about serializing instructions and memory references?

Comment: In-order execution is about in-order pipeline. For example, Computer Organization and Design 5th edition defines only in-order issue and in-order commit. So I think that first we should talk about CPU pipeline area of ordering (cpu core microarchitecture), not about cache/memory subsystem ordering... I think, in the answer I not mention memory reordering, and there is no mixing... Recker's (theoretical) question is about switching from out-of-order to in-order; I think he was interested in pipeline, because he don't mention memory in the question. And yes, if he ask about memory, you are right

Comment: My point is that in-order and o-o-o, like caches, are programmer-transparent implementations. There is no meaning in asking to simulate one or/with the other, from a programmer's perspective. It was triggered by the intermixing/combination of memory access ordering with instruction ordering in "serializing instructions" reference you provide.

Comment: The result of instructions execution is the same *as if* executed in program order. This requirement (I take it from sequential consistency definition) is held by both in-order & o-o-o for single-thread programs. It is held at the ISA level. Going to multiple thread programs requires extending the ISA with the consistency model. Still, the implementations will not be relevant for the programmer.

Comment: kavadias, Thank you, this is correct. But we don't know did Recker asked this (poorly stated) question as software programmer or as microarchitecture designer. Also, memory ordering usually named not "in-order" but as some variant of "consistency".

Comment: The question clearly refers to the compiler (its flags) and *given* only o-o-o processors available. (Thus, your answer used a program-based approach.) I believe, we can safely say the question was not aware of microarchitecture. If not anything else, most (if not all) implementations of o-o-o processors commit instructions in order, so all effects are the same as those of in-order processors. I am only aware of research proposals for o-o-o commit processors...

Comment: kavadias, can you post your own answer?

Comment: I did not think there is need for another answer. The question should not have been accepted as it is in the first place. What you have answered seems useful to me. Just placing it in the correct context. If you insist, I could post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but it depends on the CPU. Then again, the instructions themselves don't matter, the memory accesses matter.

AFAIK all CPUs guarantee that registers (and thus the internal state) appear updated in order, regardless of how execution happens. In some CPUs temporary registers are allocated with a value and the result is "written back" (register renaming, so there's no copy per se) at the appropriate time.

For memory accesses, most CPUs have memory barriers of some kind, which limit the reordering of memory accesses. There are several different kinds of memory barriers, and they differ from CPU to CPU. You can conceivably place a full memory barrier between each instruction and you'll get halfway there. If you have a multi-processor machine you might need to do some extra work to make sure the caches are also flushed. Without explicit instructions the other core may not see the results in order.

It very much depends on what you're trying to achieve and on which specific CPU. Every CPU out there is different in some way. And there won't be any magical gcc flags. In gcc the best you'll have are builtin atomic types (link below). The topic is huge. No simple answers.

**Recommended reading list:**

- http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html
- http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf

Comment: Unless it is an odd, non-coherent multiprocessor, cache flushing would not be needed; barriers and coherence ensure ordering of memory visibility. Also, if monitoring physical memory accesses and expecting "in-order" activity, prefetching might have to be disabled.

Comment: Yah, it's a mess that depends on the architecture. On x86/x64 for in order memory I/O you'd use MTRR to achieve temporal synchrony with the bus. There are just too many details that won't fit into the answer. You can look at it from an OS developer perspective (memory mapped IO), or an application developer perspective (thread synchronization) or an algorithm development perspective (lock-free algorithms, atomic updates) or even a CPU designer perspective (cache coherency, faking in-order execution). It's a huge topic and I'm sure I've left a lot out. PS compiler perspective.